# exporting environment variable with python

Tags: python, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to export an environment variable using python, but I can't seem to figure it out. 
This is what I'm trying to copy:

```
export SHELLCODE = $(python -c "print <shellcode here>")
```

This is my code:

```
subprocess.Popen('export Shellcode=$(python -c \"print "{}" \')'.format(shellcode), shell=True)
```

But when I run it, it says

```
File "<string>", line 1
print 1�Ph//shh/bin
       ^
```

Comment: Can you correct the double-quotes near print? You have three of them in your code example vs. only two in the shell example above it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to add the linux environment variable

```
$(python -c 'print "export MY_DATA=my_export"')
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I realised that now. Thanks for the suggestion